# How to set Value to Checkbox in custom module created by module creator

Tags: module, magento-1

I have created a module by module creator. I have added checkbox code in `Form.php` from `Block/Adminhtml/modulename/edit/tab/form.php`.

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'checkboxes', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('custommodule')->__('Title'),
    'name'      => 'title',
    'values' => array(
        array('value'=>'aaa','label'=>'Checkbox1'),
        array('value'=>'bbb','label'=>'Checkbox2'),
        array('value'=>'ccc','label'=>'Checkbox3'),
    ),
    /* 'checked' => array('aaa','bbb','ccc'), */
    'onclick' => "",
    'onchange' => "",
    'disabled' => false,
    'tabindex' => 1
));
```

Now How should I add this checkbox values to Database and Vice Versa how to assign value to checkbox while editing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it your own code or copied from somewhere? Just asking....

Comment: this is my code. Right now I am working on it.

Comment: I got successful in adding checkbox value to database as well as I got successful to fetch data on edit.php page too. Right now the issue is only to assign that array value to Checkbox field.

Comment: My advice: better use yes/no

Comment: I see you're setting the value by using the 'checked' attribute (althoug commented out now). It might be that the values are reset later on in the code by `$form->setValues($formValues)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code with valid param which are you using to make a checkbox in admin. by this you can get the value for every check box checked in admin form.

```
$params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if ($params != NULL) {
    $warehouses = Mage::getModel('NamespaceName_ModuleName/collect')->load($params);
    $getcheckbox = $warehouses['checkbox'];
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($getcheckbox);exit;
    $baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    if (strstr($baseurl, 'index.php')) {
        $baseurl = str_replace('/index.php', '', $baseurl);
    }
    ?>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var access = '<?php echo $getcheckbox; ?>';
            var myacess = access.split(",");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < myacess.length; i++) {
                jQuery('#checkbox_' + myacess[i]).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow bellow steps

Step : 1 Add code in (Block/Adminhtml/modulename/edit/tab/form.php)

```
$model = Mage::registry('modulename_data');
$fieldset->addField('title[]', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesman')->__('Title'),
            'name'      => 'title[]',
            'values' => array(
                array('value'=>'aaa','label'=>'Checkbox1'),
                array('value'=>'bbb','label'=>'Checkbox2'),
                array('value'=>'ccc','label'=>'Checkbox3'),
            ),
            'checked' => unserialize($model->getTitle())
        ));
```

Step : 2 Add code in admin controller (ModuleNamespace\modulename\controllers\Adminhtml\YourcontrollernameController.php)

```
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    $data['title'] = serialize($data['title']);
    ...
```